# Работа с UILabel

Tags: swift, label

Доброго времени суток!
Вопрос такой: 
Допустим у меня есть лейбл, у которого есть констрейнт  width. Бывает такое, что когда текст лейбла больше его ширины, то лейбл выглядит следующим образом "БлаБлаБла...", а мне бы хотелось, чтобы он выглядел вот так "БлаБла..ла". Как мне этого достичь? Есть ли какое-то готовое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `IB` выберите Ваш `UILabel`, далее `Attributes inspector`-> `Line Break` -> `Truncate Middle`

Можно и через код. Пример на **Swift 3**:

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle;
```

Comment: Отлично! Это почти то, что нужно. А подскажи еще чуть-чуть, пожалуйста. Мне нужно чтобы именно двумя символами заканчивалось

Comment: Думаю, что нужно найти сначала сколько букв вмещает в себя лейбл и потом уже просто все будет.

Comment: Данная функция ставит троеточие в центре строки. Если Вы хотите именно два символа в конце, вам придется писать это в ручную. Как идея можете создать словарик, где ключом будет оригинал строки и в значение заносите новую строку. Вам надо считать, сколько символов вмещается в UILabel, далее берете range и заменяете 3, 4 и 5-ую буквы с конца тремя точками, и вы получите нужный эффект.

Comment: да, я это понимаю. Вот пытаюсь узнать как найти сколько сиимволов вмещается в мой UILabel, только пока не получается. очень много информации на obj-c  и почти ничего на swift :(

Comment: Посмотрите эту ссылку, возможно она Вам поможет: https://gist.github.com/ViccAlexander/0224ab078f76a3af6d79986369d5240b

Comment: вот тут опять же нужно знать то, сколько символов вмещает в себя лейбл. Чего пока что мне достичь не удалось. Спасибо за попытку)

Comment: Так оптимизируйте под себя, скажем каждый лейбл показывает 15 символов например =)

Comment: Это, конечно, хитрое, но не оптимальное решение)) Ладно, Я еще подумаю, если ничего не придумаю, то отмечу Ваше решение, как верное.